# How to find the package that contains the specific data

Tags: r

I know how to check the existing datasets of a package.
but my question is, given the name of the dataset, how to find out the name of the package that contains the data?

e.g. I want to find out the package name which includes the data **worms** in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this, in the documentation the package name will be included:

```
help(worms, try.all.packages = TRUE)
```

As pointed out by Ananda, the **try.all.packages** argument makes *help* to search in all the
     packages in the known library trees.

Comment: Are you asking a follow-up question, as you seem to be doing? Or are you offering an answer? If the former, please use the "comments" instead. If the latter, then try to rephrase your "answer" as an actual answer and verify that it is valid.

Comment: you are right, it works. it didn`t work on my end because I didn`t install the package clusterSim (which includes worms) yet, that`s why it displays nothing when I do that. but generally, it definitely works. thank you and I am all set!

Comment: @ananda: I had not the worms dataset, so I could not check my answer.

Comment: @KarlForner, my point about checking is that I'm not sure whether this works as is if the packages is not already loaded and in the search path. I would assume you need something like (for example, for the "diamonds" dataset if you knew you had used it before, but can't remember which package it's in) `help(diamonds, try.all.packages=TRUE, help_type="text")`. The `try.all.packages` looks in all packages in your libraries, whether loaded or not. The `help_type = "text"` just tells R to display the result in the console.